# React backpress prints axios response on the screen

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, axios

I've created a React App, which works fine, but the issue is, when I click the back button, the screen goes white and prints the response of the axios get or post request.

Here is my useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function loadIBooks() {
            const response = await axios.get(
                `/Bookss?_type=${BooksType}&_page=${page}`
            );

            setBookss(response.data.data);

            if (response.data.data.length === 0) {
                setNoBookss(true);
            } else setNoBookss(false);
            setLoading(false);
        }
        loadBookss();
    }, [page, BooksType]);
```

And this is my route's data:

```
router.get("/books", async (req, res) => {
    const allbooks = await bookSchema
        .find({
            status: "Published",
            bookType: req.query._type,
        })
        .sort({ _id: -1 });

    res.json({
        data: allbooks,
        status: res.status,
    });
});
```

**It first shows data correctly, but when I go to next page, and come back, it prints the axios response.**

Comment: Not sure if this was just a typo or not, but you defined the function `loadIBooks` and then you call a function called `loadBookss`...different spellings. Also, you route is `/books`, but in your axios call you request `/bookss`

Comment: Hi, yes it is a type. At first it works fine, but when I click back button, it shows the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this issue by adding the static part in the server.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
    app.use(express.static("./client/build"));
    const path = require("path");
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    });
}
```